# How can i update all row except one in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table:-

```
|   num   | name     |  value |
----------------------------------
|    1    | name1    |   1    |
|    2    | name2    |   1    |
|    1    | name1    |   1    |
|    4    | name4    |   2    |
|    1    | name1    |   3    |
```

I want to update each value column with 5 **except one row** where column num and name both are same

like I have tried if anyone corrects it

```
UPDATE table t 
            SET
            value = 5
            FROM table  t2
            WHERE
            t1.num = t2.num AND
            t1.name = t2.name
```

but it updates all row I want that a single row (anyone) not updated

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you are trying to do.  Which row in your example would be the one not to update?

Comment: I have mentioned any single row @Kevin

Comment: So you just want a random row not to update?

Comment: except  one row(either you called it one random row) all will be updated @Kevin

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer but your question still makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

```
UPDATE table t 
    SET value = 5
    FROM (SELECT t2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num, name ORDER BY num) as seqnum
          FROM table t2
         ) t2
    WHERE t.num = t2.num AND
          t.name = t2.name AND
          t2.seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: What is the t1 @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @bala . . . It was copied from your code, but obviously a typo.

Comment: t2.seqnum > 1; is not working it update all row. But if i put like  t2.seqnum < 1; then query result is zero

Comment: @bala . . . The `t2.seqnum` should prevent one row from being updated.

Answer (score -2):

Please try to use this type of method you will get proper update.

```
update  table<table_name>  set <column_name_3> = <value> where id not in (
select distinct wcw.id from  table<table_name> wcw join (select <column_name_1>, <column_name_2>, min(id) as ids from table<table_name>
                                                        group by <column_name_1>, <column_name_2>) wcw2
on  <column_name_1> = wcw2 <column_name_1> where wcw.<column_name_3> <> false and wcw.id > wcw2.ids
    )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).